# CasperJS Loading resource failed with status=fail (HTTP 0)

Tags: ssl, web-scraping, phantomjs, web-crawler, casperjs

Every time my script tries to open the "Create Job Posting" form of a site that I'm trying to crawl, the logs would always result to this:

```
[info] [phantom] Step _step 9/18 http://www.samplesite.com/jobs/edit (HTTP 200)
[info] [phantom] Step _step 9/18: done in 12780ms.
[debug] [phantom] Navigation requested: url=about:blank, type=Other, willNavigate=true, isMainFrame=false
[debug] [phantom] Navigation requested: url=http://www.samplesite.com/jobs/edit, type=Other, willNavigate=true, isMainFrame=false
[warning] [phantom] Loading resource failed with status=fail: http://www.samplesite.com/jobs/edit
[warning] [phantom] Casper.waitFor() timeout
[info] [phantom] Step _step 10/18 http://www.samplesite.com/jobs/edit (HTTP 0)
[info] [phantom] Step _step 10/18: done in 22814ms.
[warning] [phantom] Casper.waitFor() timeout
```

I tried to open the site manually yet it seems to be perfectly fine. Checked the error screenshot and HTML script of the last step with CasperJS and it would always look like this: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QGYmB.png)

I tried to do some research for any workaround on this issue and some were suggesting on adding `--ignore-ssl-errors=true` or `--ssl-protocol=any` on my command but these didn't work on my end.

On my JS script, I didn't add any special methods. I only did use the plain `casper.click()` or `casper.open()` in opening the page.

I'm using casperjs 1.0.0 and phantomjs 2.1.1

Comment: We did an update on the script and this time it has resulted to HTTP 200 but still with the same error "Loading resource failed"